# Get portion of page HTML via AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am trying to get everything inside a div with the id "ajax_container" via AJAX. The AJAX response contains all the page HTML, but when I use the selector to isolate the contents of the div, it returns undefined.

```
 $(".ajax-click").click(function(e){
     $.ajax({
         url: $(this).attr("href"),
         success: function(response) {
           alert(response);
           var html = $('#ajax_container', response).html();
           alert(html);
         }
     });
 e.preventDefault();
 });
```

HTML trying to be selected:

```
<html>
<body>
    <div id="ajax_container">
        <p>Content here</p>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: please show the html that you are trying to select

Comment: @Sanpopo added to original question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're just trying to get a snippet of a page, I'd suggest using `.load`
https://api.jquery.com/load/

```
$( "#target" ).load( "ajax/test.html #ajax_container" );
```

In the code snippet above, you're loading a page named `test.html`, but just retrieving the element with the ID of `#ajax_container`.

So your snippet would look something like:

```
$(".ajax-click").click(function(e){
     // get the element clicked
     var $clickedElement = $(this),
          pageToLoad = $clickedElement.prop("href");


     $( "#ajax_container" ).load( "ajax/test.html " + pageToLoad );

     e.preventDefault();
 });
```

It seems like you're trying to implement client side routing. If you're trying to replace a container with ajax content then you should use a library that will help you achieve this. A solid library to use is Path.js. Below is a link with a small example and it is similar to what you want to acheive.

http://www.javascriptoo.com/path-js

Comment: How do I dynamically select the page? I was trying to use $(this).attr("href") before.

Comment: You can build the value of the selector dynamically as well. I'll update my answer.

Comment: Sorry, I meant the page being loaded, not the target. The page being loaded is the href attribute of the clicked object.

Comment: I need to get the contents of #ajax_container inside the clicked object's href attribute (in your example, you have it as "ajax/test.html"). Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Ahh I see now. I updated my answer to reflect that. All you need to do is concatenate the href attribute on to the selector for the load call.

Comment: There was Javascript on the page that is being loaded that seems to be getting stripped. Anyway to bring that through?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/47609/discussion-between-david-and-rgilkes)

Answer (score 1):

You need [.load()](https://api.jquery.com/load/) to do that

```
$("#TargetID").load("ajax/test.html #ajax_container");
                 //^^URL            ^^ element you want to load
```

---

```
$('#ajax_container', response).html();
```

is equal to

```
$('#ajax_container').find(response).html();
```

There is no element with id `ajax_container` so it return undefined

Answer (score 1):

With your current function, you should use `.html()` in order to set the html string to the element.

For example

```
 $(".ajax-click").click(function(e){
     $.ajax({
         url: $(this).attr("href"),
         success: function(response) {
           $('#ajax_container').load(response);
           alert("Success");
         }
     });
 e.preventDefault();
 });
```

See https://api.jquery.com/html/

However, as others have said `.load()` works too. (https://api.jquery.com/html/)

```
 $(".ajax-click").click(function(e){
     $('#ajax_container').load($(this).attr("href"), function() {
         alert("Load successful.");
     });
 e.preventDefault();
 });
```

I would recommend using `.load()` over `.html()` as the former is cleaner.